# Removing time interval independence (AKA creating carryover)

Tags: r, time

I'm trying to write a program for an object assignment process, so I'll give a little overview of the actual process, and then explain where my main hangup is.
So objects are coming into a system, and there are multiple workers/servers in the system that handle the objects on a first in/first out basis.
Since each worker has a specific/unique time schedule, I split the time slots up into 30 minute intervals over each week (2 intervals per hour * 24 hours in a day * 7 days in a week = 336 intervals per week).

My issue is coming from time independence.

During some, or most shifts actually, there will be carryover of these objects.  As in, whatever doesn't get finished in time interval one SHOULD carryover to time interval two, but I can't figure out a way to do that.  So for me, every time interval is a fresh slate, which isn't good!

If anyone can help me figure out a way to deal with that, I would greatly appreciate it! I'll attach the code that I currently have.  If this seems like too "personal" of a request that would not be of much benefit to the community, I understand, and would be willing to compensate for someone's time if they were able to solve my issue :) Unless I'm not allowed to say that, in which case scratch that thought.

```
processobjects <- function(workers = 100,t.end  = 30,Ta , Ts = 40.59/60){

  t.clock <- 0    # sim time

  t1 <- 0         # time for next arrival
  t2 <- rep(t.end,workers)     # time for next departure
  tn <- rep(t.clock,workers)    # tmp var for last event time
  tb <- rep(0,workers)          # tmp var for last busy-time start
  n <- 0           # number in system
  s <- rep(0,workers)           # cumulative number-time product
  b <- rep(0,workers)           # total busy time
  c <- 0          # total completions
  qc <- 0         # plot instantaneous queue size
  tc <- 0         # plot time delta
  plotSamples <- 100
  set.seed(1)
  workersavailability <-rep(0,workers)

  arrive11 <- list()

  while (t.clock < t.end) {

    arrive11 <- c(arrive11,list(t1,t2))


    for(i in 1:workers){

      if (t1 < t2[i]) {      # arrival event
        if ( workersavailability[i] == 1 & 0 %in% workersavailability){
          next
        }
        workersavailability[i] = 1
        t.clock <- t1
        n <- n + 1  # number in system
        t1 <- t.clock + rexp(1, 1/Ta) # time for next arrival
        # cat("t1 arrive is ", t1,"\n")
        if(n <= workers & n != 0) { 
          t2[i] <- t.clock + rexp(1, 1/Ts)  # exponential  interarrival     period

        }
        break
      } else {            # departure event

        t.clock <- t2[i]
        n <- n - 1
        c <- c + 1
        if (n >= workers) { 
          t2[i] <- t.clock + rexp(1, 1/Ts)  # exponential  service period
        }
        else { 
          t2[i] <- t.end
          workersavailability[i] = 0
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  print (c)
}
# u <- b/t.clock       # utilization B/T
# N <- s/t.clock       # mean queue length (see the Load Average notes)
# x <- c/t.clock       # mean throughput C/T
# r <- N/x             # mean residence time (from Little's law: Q = XR)
# q <- sum(qc)/max(tc) # estimated queue length for plot

library(xlsx)
ccu <- read.xlsx("objects.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1,header = F)
ccuarrivalrate <- ccu/30
workers
for (i in 1 : 336){
  processobjects(Ta = 1/ccuarrivalrate[i,1])
}
```